# "'Network Drive' refers to a location that is unavailable" while UNC works

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, mappeddrive, windows-explorer

### Situation:

- Environment is a Windows Domain with 160+ Clients, several DCs. No WINS. DNS working.
- Fileserver is a Windows Server 2012 R2, patched regularly, SMB shares, proper NTFS and share permissions.
- Clients are Windows 7 x64 machines. Clients get drive mappings via Group Policies.

### Problem:

Random users receive the error message "Z:\ refers to a location that is unavailable. ..." when they want to create a new folder. *Accessing* the folder over Windows explorer works. Also *renaming* of files and folders works. *Creating* new folders and files works also in Windows Explorer, when the location in question is accessed over UNC paths. Creating new files and folders also works when accessing the *drive mapping* via a program such as DoubleCommander. Also saving files from Office applications to the network drive works.

### Our measurements included:

- deleting the drive mapping and creating it again
- verifying the correct order in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order
- rebooting server and client
- uninstalling antivirus software from client (none on server)
- accessing the drive from other profiles from the same PC (same error on some, works for others)
- creating folder from cmd (works)
- accessing the drive from the same user on another PC (works)

I appreciate any advice on how to track this down further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access based enumeration enabled on the share?

Just resolved an extremely similar sounding issue. Client was Windows 10 in our case, but the same issue and resolution.

http://clintboessen.blogspot.co.uk/2016/07/bug-with-windows-7-and-access-based.html

Comment: When posting a link please also include the main points in your answer in case the link is ever broken.

Comment: Although the rights are set as proposed in the linked blog post, I was able to create a new folder after disabling ABE. Therefore I mark this answer as most helpful. Thank you!